# Selective division of pandas data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have two Pandas dataframes, one with negative numbers, and one with positive numbers, that look something like this:

```
Columns 1  2  3            Columns 1  2  3
Rows                       Rows
1      -4 -6 -5            1       9  3  2
2      -2 -8 -4            2       6  4  5
3      -8 -8 -3            3       8  2  5
```

Then I have another Pandas dataframe with the same dimensions, but with negative and positive numbers like so:

```
Columns 1  2  3
Rows
1      -2  3 -4
2      -1 -2  2
3       6 -8  3
```

For each element in this mixed dataframe, if the value is negative, I want to divide it by the corresponding element from the negative dataframe, and if the value is positive, I want to divide it by the corresponding element from the positive dataframe. The result would look like this:

```
Columns  1     2    3
Rows
1      0.5   1.0  0.8
2      0.5  0.25  0.4
3     0.75   1.0  0.6
```

What's the most pythonic and/or efficient way to do this? I'll have on the order of 10,000 mixed dataframes with 50 rows and 105 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about efficiency, but you could use `where` to do it pretty cleanly:

```
>>> df1
   0  1  2
0  3  8  7
1  9  9  3
2  1  1  9
>>> df2
   0  1  2
0 -3 -7 -8
1 -4 -6 -3
2 -8 -8 -3
>>> df3
    0  1  2
0 -10  7  1
1 -10 -4  9
2   7 -8  0
>>> df3/df1.where(df3 >= 0, df2)
          0         1         2
0  3.333333  0.875000  0.142857
1  2.500000  0.666667  3.000000
2  7.000000  1.000000  0.000000
```

Comment: Wow, that's way cleaner than I was hoping. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach, which appears faster.  It basically creates a boolean mask over the mixed dataframe and then divides it by the appropriate positive or negative dataframe.  Because positive and negative are mutually exclusive, the result can be summed to create the denominator.  This is then multiplied by mixed dataframe to get the desired result.

Based on your original data:

```
>>> df3 * (df3.gt(0) / df2 + df3.lt(0) / df1)
      0     1    2
0  0.50  1.00  0.8
1  0.50  0.25  0.4
2  0.75  1.00  0.6
```

With a larger 10kx10k DataFrame:

```
df_pos = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10000, 10000)).abs()
df_neg = -pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10000, 10000)).abs()
df_mixed = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10000, 10000))
```

Timing comparison with the solution of @DSM which is arguably simpler:

```
%timeit -n 10 df_mixed * (df_mixed.ge(0) / df_pos + df_mixed.lt(0) / df_neg)
10 loops, best of 3: 1.45 s per loop

%timeit -n 10 df_mixed / df_pos.where(df_mixed >= 0, df_neg)
10 loops, best of 3: 6.5 s per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, good to know. I'll switch to your method if @DSM's method starts looking too slow for me.